# Blank page open when I tap on Paypal from BrainTree payment page in iOS 10

Tags: ios, paypal, ios10, braintree

I have integrated [BRAINTREE SDK](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios) into my app. Also I have following all the steps of [PayPal/Client-Side Implementation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/client-side/ios/v4#implementing-delegate-protocols).

It is working perfectly in iOS 9. But PAYPAL functionality is not working in iOS 10 only. When I tap on the PAYPAL button from the below 1st screen, blank page has been opened as shown in below 2nd image.

[image]

[image]

But when I want to pay with PAYPAL in iOS 9, then it is redirecting following page same as below image, but not working in iOS 10 Devices.

[image]

I am not sure why this happens for iOS 10 only.

Also I have added [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/issues/276).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am also seeing this issue when using the Web integration on iOS10

Comment: I am using braintree-2.29.0.min.js hosted by braintree and am having the same issue on an iPhone 5s (iOS 10.0.2) and iPhone 6SE (iOS 10.0.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, got the solution. It happens due to UITabBarController which is implemented into my app.

So earlier I was presenting payment screeen (BTDropInViewController) same as below :-

```
[self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So Now I am using this instead of above line,

```
[APPDELEGATE.navigationController presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

//#define APPDELEGATE ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) //Global object of AppDelegate
//@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController; //which is declared into AppDelegate.h
```

Hope, this is what you're looking for. Any concern get back to me. :)